# Dynamically inserting html from external file and updating the database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, dom

I need some suggestions on how to approach this. I want to allow users to create sections of website. The code so far is working but since I am new to back-end I feel like there is better, more elegant way to approach this. I am open to any approaches, as long as the code is kept as concise as possible.

> 1. The user clicks "add section" button (there would be different types of sections to choose from), the html of each section will be stored in an external file
> 2. The id of the section should be inserted into the database (alongside some other details such as user uniqid)
> 3. The section should be inserted inside a div

At the moment this is how I have approached it:

```
if (isset($_POST["add_section"])) {
    $section_id = $_POST["add_section"];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO sections (user_id, section_id) VALUES (?, ?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $row['user_id'], $section_id);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

---

The value of the button is the id of the section passed to the database.

```
<form method="post">
    <button class="button_1" value="navigation_ht" name="add_section>Seleccionar</button>
</form>
```

---

I want to allow the user to be able to include up to 3 sections.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sections WHERE user_id = '{$row['user_id']}'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        include('shared/'.$row['section_id'].'.php');
    }
}
```

I was considering to do the following, but if the section is not created, there is error message:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sections WHERE user_id = '{$row['user_id']}'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    include('shared/'.$row['section_id'].'.php');
    include('shared/'.$row['section_id'].'.php');
    include('shared/'.$row['section_id'].'.php');
}
```

Comment: This code is far from complete. I my opinion it cannot be reviewed in this state.

Answer (score 1):

This looks very clean, there is not much to improve upon.

However, there is a glaring security issue:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Your code should not allow malicious JavaScript to be stored inside of the db.